# How to use a magnifying glass or any lens to enhance small light power?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

I am currently trying  to amplify a tiny amount of light so that a photodiode will recognize it.

In order to amplify the light I thought about using a magnifying glass since I got to know that such convex glasses might help to spread light. I was positively surprised as I saw the result as the light really got amplified using a magnifying glass (see drawing). However  the issue is that the magnifying glass requires a distance of 9-10 cm between the light source and the glass in order to spread the light in the required strong way.

I was wondering whether there is any way to get the same light amount spread without having a gap between the lens / glass and the light source (or having a small gap)?

[image]

Comment: You can use a large area sensor, even though that leads to other problems (high frequency noise and response time). A solar cell might do just fine. Please not that you are not "amplifying" light, you are only collecting more of it. What a lens does is to trade "area against angle", and in this case it only works because the light that you want to detect is nearly parallel. Now, you can use a mirror instead of lens, or a combination of mirrors or multiple lenses, which will greatly reduce the thickness of the setup, but that's ultimately an engineering optimization.

Comment: Thx! Do I understand correctly that u mean that a solar cell will sprad the light as the magnifying glass does?

Comment: A solar cell is basically a large area photo diode, except that it doesn't cost nearly as much. The signal to noise ratio that you will get out of a solar cell is, of course, horrible, since the capacitance is so large. On the other hand, since you didn't tell us anything about the signal that you want to measure, that may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Basically due to the given circumstances an led light becomes weak however visible. Unfortunately the photodiode ( which will be connected to a microcontroller) is not able to recognize the light in order to take further action. Using a magnifying glass the photodiode recognizes the light. The gap of arround 9-10 cm distrurbs me using the glass....

Comment: There are a couple of things you have to do. 1) use a small lens in front of the LED to create a narrow directional beam 2) use a small lens in front of the photodiode 3) modulate the signal from the LED at e.g. 1 kHz and use a synchronous detector on the highly amplified ac signal from the photodiode. These three measures will buy you three or four orders of magnitude of sensitivity while making the setup insensitive to stray light.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to use a small laser pointer instead of the LED (they are like $5 today). The power budget is the same, but the beam will be narrow and stay focused over several meters. I would still modulate with a simple one transistor switch and  use an AC detector. Your microcontroller probably has an ADC, so all you would have to do is to write a little bit of software to drive the laser and to demodulate the photodiode signal.

Comment: Well I like your first suggestion. In 1. and 2. you tell me to use a lens. Even as a rookie I know that there are too many options on lenses. Can you tell me what kind of lens you mean? One question on the sync. detector..i understand that I require a sync. detection...what is the device/tool behind that?

Comment: In your case the most simple convex plastic lens with a couple of cm of focal length will do. Synchronous detectors come in all sizes. A simple circuit is e.g.  Figure 4 in "Synchronous Detectors Facilitate Precision, Low-Level Measurements" by Luis Orozco.

Comment: Thx for interesting link. I am currently trying to learn more about Lock-in amplifier. Figure 4 depicts a schematic; however I still try to figure out how I may realize it using an atmega328 / attiny85 microcontroller.... ps. why dont you put your input as answer..

Comment: Just to be sure, did you put your setup in a completely dark environment? If not I'm sure you only see the surrounding light on your PD.

Comment: well without the light input i have a value of 0 on the PD ( environment is pretty dark but not completely)....so with the light input I have a small value on the PD which i am attempting to increase...

Answer (score 1):

A lens with more curvature will have a focus point closer to the lens. Unfortunately, they are more difficult to make. Since these lenses need good precision, they are made with glass and poor quality lenses are usually discarded.

On the up side, LEDs and sensors are designed to work as a pair and may be used up to (about) one meter, so lenses are not needed.

Comment: Thanks! Well unfortunately that LED light power gets weakened  and the significantly weakened light should be recognized by the photodiode. Since the light is too weak I had to make use of a magnifying glass..

Comment: There might be a solution, did you get the LED and photodiode together? Does the wavelength of maximum output of the LED match the wavelength of maximum sensitivity of the photodiode?

Comment: I did my homework on selecting the right photodiode....which has its peak sensitivity at 580nm

Comment: How close together can the LED and photodiode be? less than 1 cm? What do you want to do with the beam?

Comment: Pls check the updated drawing above! The issue is the very low level light that I wanna have detected by the photodiode

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a lens with a shorter focal length. As a rough number, you can work with a LED to lens distance of twice the focal length of the lens. Note that that is what you are doing with your magnifying glass. It's possible to get lenses with focal lengths less than 10 mm, so you can operate at less than 2 cm separation. Since I assume you don't want to spend much money on this, I recommend an optical surplus site. Surplusshed.com is a good place to start, and they have some very low-cost items.

And you seem to misunderstand how a lens works in this case. What you are trying to do is focus the LED on the photodiode. Depending on the size of the LED vs the diode, for best results you may have to get a photodiode with a bigger active area.

And finally, the simplest way to do what you seem to want to do is simply butt the LED against the front of the photodiode.

Comment: Thx! Well basically I want to reduce the gap between the lens and light source whilst the light gets powered/amplified somehow so that it is signficant enough for the photodiode. I did consider on selecting a photodiode with a bigge sensitivity area.